# assignDetectionsToTracks from Matlab to python 2.7

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-cvst

I was wondering if there is any similar function to assignDetectionsToTracks from Matlab in Python. 
I know that in that function Matlab Munkre's algorithm is implemented but I suspect that more code is programmed.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't find an identical implementation, however you can use Hungarian algorithm using `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`

[click here for further details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)